# Error while dumping coverage data (code 5013).Selenium using java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation

All of my script is working perfectly fine while in error log its showing me with this error, Here is the stack trace

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:83)
atorg.eclipse.eclemma.internal.core.MemoryExecutionDataSource.readFrom(MemoryExecutionDataSource.java:68)
at org.eclipse.eclemma.internal.core.launching.AgentServer.run(AgentServer.java:114)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

**Message below the stack trace is**

```
    [TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate] Launching:
  Classpath: C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse\java-2019-09\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\488\0\.cp\lib\testng-remote.jar C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse-workspace1\Auto\bin C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.testng_7.0.0.r201908191551.jar C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\activation-1.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\ATExcelReport.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\client-combined-3.141.59.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-codec-1.13.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-collections4-4.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-collections4-4.4.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-compress-1.19.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-exec-1.3.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-logging-1.2.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\curvesapi-1.06.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\guava-25.0-jre.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\jfreechart.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\jfreechart-dependency-jcommon-1.0.12.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\junit-4.12.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\log4j-1.2.17.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\okhttp-3.11.0.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\okio-1.14.0.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-3.15.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-4.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-examples-4.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-excelant-4.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-3.15.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-scratchpad-4.1.1.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0 (1).jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\sqljdbc4.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar C:\Selenium jarsAll\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
  VMArgs:    -ea -javaagent:C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse\java-2019-09\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\457\0\.cp\jacocoagent.jar=includes=*,excludes=,exclclassloader=sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader,output=tcpclient,port=7688
  Class:     org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
  Args:      -serport 7689 -protocol json -d C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse-workspace1\Auto\test-output C:\Users\hamzam\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1227229154\testng-customsuite.xml
java -ea -javaagent:C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse\java-2019-09\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\457\0\.cp\jacocoagent.jar=includes=*,excludes=,exclclassloader=sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader,output=tcpclient,port=7688 -classpath C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse\java-2019-09\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\488\0\.cp\lib\testng-remote.jar:C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse-workspace1\Auto\bin:C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.testng_7.0.0.r201908191551.jar:C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar:C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar:C:\Users\hamzam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\activation-1.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\ATExcelReport.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\client-combined-3.141.59.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-codec-1.13.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-collections4-4.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-collections4-4.4.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-compress-1.19.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-exec-1.3.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-logging-1.2.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\curvesapi-1.06.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\guava-25.0-jre.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\jaxb-impl-2.3.2.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\jfreechart.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\jfreechart-dependency-jcommon-1.0.12.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\junit-4.12.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\log4j-1.2.17.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\okhttp-3.11.0.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\okio-1.14.0.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-3.15.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-4.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-examples-4.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-excelant-4.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-3.15.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\poi-scratchpad-4.1.1.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0 (1).jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\sqljdbc4.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:C:\Selenium jarsAll\xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG -serport 7689 -protocol json -d C:\Users\hamzam\eclipse-workspace1\Auto\test-output C:\Users\hamzam\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1227229154\testng-customsuite.xml
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace along with your code trials?

Comment: above  mentioned is  the complete stack  trace and the message is given  below  it .